# Functional way to update a Map

Tags: scala

I would like to check if a key exists inside a Map and if exists, i would like to increment 1 on value. If not exists, I would like to put a new item on Map with value equals 1.

What's the 'functional way' to do it? I've wrote it using find and fold but it's look kinda strange.

```
val updatedScore = currentScores
  .find(s => s._1.equals(score))
  .fold(score -> 1)(s => s._1 -> (s._2 + 1))

val newScores = currentScores + updatedScore
```

Anyone have a better solution to do the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
val newScores = currentScores + (score -> (currentScores.getOrElse(score, 0) + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val ret: mutable.Map[Int, Int] = mutable.Map[Int, Int]().withDefaultValue(1)
val arg = 5
ret.update(arg, ret(5)+1)
```

Comment: "Functional" usually means "avoiding side effects", among other things. `update` is a side effect.

Comment: I don't get this: why is this a side effect? I mean- this whole question is about updating a mutable map, is'n it?

Comment: This is a valid answer. The accepted answer does what OP wanted; however, it is very inefficient, since the entire Map has to get copied over to new Map.  Mutable data structures are in scala for a reason, this might be a good use case for them.

Comment: The performance is actually comparable, [the official docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) say that both run in effectively constant time. [Here is a very simple timing showing similar performance](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/MCRDGXZAQQ).

Comment: user7938511 The map need not be mutable, as @nmat's answer shows. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) and [here](http://panavtec.me/functional-programming-notes-side-effects) are simple defintions of side effects. The goal of FP is to make changes in state as transparent as possible. Functions with side effects run counter to that goal. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) for more info

Comment: @Akavall sorry, just realized you were not tagged. See above ^^

Comment: @evan058, Very interesting. That means, that in the accepted answer the entire map is not being copied over, and scala has a more efficient implementation under the hood. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
val updatedScore = score -> (currentScores(score)+ 1)
val newScores= currentScores - score + newScore
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to count, consider using a MultiMap, i.e.: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html. Since you're accumulating counts, there doesn't seem to be a good reason to avoid side effects.